# Using placeholders to insert HTML

Tags: internet-explorer-9, visual-studio-2008-sp1, ssrs-2008-r2

I've built a SSRS report which will become a dashboard. I'm using kiosk mode in IE 9 with this command line to display my report:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -k 
"http://MyServer/_vti_bin/ReportServer?http://MyServer/MySite/OC/Reports/MyDashboard.rdl&rc:Toolbar=false"
```

When the IE page comes up there is a greyed out right scrollbar.

Numerous posts mention plugging in this kind of thing into the HTML:

```
<body style="overflow:hidden">
```

Research indicates that I need to use a *placeholder* to add static HTML to a report.

I did the following:

1. Dropped on a text box
2. Clicked *in* the textbox to change do data entry type mode (took a while to work that one out)
3. Right click in the text box/create placeholder
4. Put the above html text in the *Value* field

Now regardless of what options I select (HTML or Text) or whether or not I put anything in Label, when I press OK, I get:

```
<Value>
Specify the value of the placeholder
```

Has anyone come across this before?, or can anyone suggest a different way to make kiosk look like it should?

[image: Placeholder Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the complete list of tags that will render as HTML when defined as placeholder text:

```
Hyperlinks: <A HREF>

Fonts: <FONT>

Header, style and block elements: <H{n}>, <DIV>, <SPAN>,<P>, <DIV>, <LI>, <HN>

Text format: <B>, <I>, <U>, <S>

List handling: <OL>, <UL>, <LI>
```

So, when importing HTML content into a report, we need to pay attention to the supported tags. If the HTML content includes HTML tags that are not supported, the HTML that is shown in the rendered report may differ from the original HTML.

And about the thing

```
<body style="overflow:hidden">
```

It's a bit complex one. You have to edit in your ReportManager CSS, not in report level expression.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that will come in handy. I'll try that next week. Do you have any insight on the error message, which appears no matter what I type into the value (i.e. 'TEST')

Comment: As it's a value, it should start with = normally like ="TEST". Read about SSRS expressions.

Comment: Excellent, yes it needed an = sign in front and then the error goes away. And I will also apply the external stylesheet on a URL and document that when complete.